# Changing from initial layout to main layout for widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created a widget for my application, but I require a initial loading layout before I show my main widget layout. I have made a load up layout as a initial and my main layout. I tried to use RemoteViews to show up my main widget layout after my stuff has finished loading at onUpdate method but it does not show up.

Is there any way to switch from the initial layout to the main layout?

**Edit**

Sorry for the late reply, hope I am showing the right blocks. What I did was to set the initial layout at the app widget properties and change to the actual layout that i am showing at the onUpdate method via a service in another class file.

Here are my codes:

The Widget info

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/initial_layout"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

This is what i typed for my onUpdate method:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }

        //start service
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, WeatherNotificationService.class);
        context.startService((myIntent));

    }
```

Here is the code i typed within the service method.

```
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(WeatherNotificationService.this.getApplicationContext());
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),SafetyWidget.class);
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
            new CommonOpearation().showToast(getApplicationContext(), appWidgetIds.length+"");
            for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
                int appWidgetID = appWidgetIds[i];
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd/MM/yyyy");
                formatter.setLenient(false);
                Date a= new Date();

                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.todayDate,formatter.format(a));
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.psiTime,currentNowCast.getCurrentPsiObj().getDatenTime()); 
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.psiTV,currentNowCast.getCurrentPsiObj().getPsi()); 

remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewTodayTemp,currentNowCast.getCurrentTemp().getTemp());
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewNearestRegion, nowCastWeather.getNwo().getRegion());   
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.hospTV, contact.getName());    
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetID, remoteViews);
```

RemoteViews function is to show up the appropriate layout when it is called at onUpdate? This is puzzling...

Comment: Show what you did so far.

Comment: Both the layouts are on the same activity?

Comment: @micro.pravi he's talking about appwidgets, there are no activities involved, only XML layouts rendered via RemoteViews